# How to add a foreign key, through the interface, to ASPNET Membership provider?

Tags: asp.net-membership, foreign-keys

I'm using VWD 2008 Express Edition with MVC and I am trying to add a foreign key from my database to the ASPNET Membership database's Users table. Is this possible using the user interface or do I have to scrounge up some SQL every time I want to do this?

Edit: After thinking about this for a minute, I realized that maybe having an FK to a different DB wasn't even possible... I really didn't think about my question thoroughly enough, did I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for that. Script your database once you created the membership tables and use your script from there on. (BTW, you [don't have to use that table structure to use the membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) if it doesn't suit your needs.)